# Sync AzureSQL Database to On-Premises Warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, teradata, etl

How would you sync data between an Azure Sql database and an on-premises data warehouse like Teradata?

Comment: There is likely plenty of documentation about data sync. Maybe start with the Azure site and related docs?

Comment: since your on-premises DB is likely behind the firewall there are two ways. One - to punch a tunnel inside of it, setup a linked server on Azure side and run table-by-table insert/select. Second - use a jdbc bridge to bulk select/insert between the two, which would allow you to exclude the necessity of the proxy configuration.